# Text file downloaded in browser

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

I encountered a strange behaviour today. Say, I have a localhost and several text files. Normally I would type `localhost/myfile.txt` and browser will display the content. But instead, every browser asks me to download the file.

The text file content is simple, just a bunch of random characters like this

```
dasddasd dasdasd sdas dsad 122323
```

Using Firefox console I read the following error message:

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

Of course I had changed character encoding in Notepad++ to UTF-8 or UTF-8 Without BOM. No success!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the character encoding needs to be specified in the HTTP headers. If you're using Apache you could try adding this to your httpd.conf:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```